# Concentration bound on sum of indepenent Chi variables

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, normal-distribution, concentration-of-measure

Let $X = \left(Z_1^2 + \dots + Z_N^2 \right)^{1/2}$, where $Z_1, \dots, Z_N$ are $N$ independent, normally distributed random variables with mean 0 and standard deviation $\sigma$. $X$ is distributed according to a [Chi distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_distribution). Consider a sequence of $K$ such variables: $X_1, \dots, X_K$, where $X_k$'s are independent.

> What can be said about the following probability?
> $$\mathbb{P}\left[\left\vert \sum_{k=1}^{K} X_k - K\sqrt{N}\sigma\right\vert \ge t\right]$$

Comment: Is $n$ supposed to be $N$?

Comment: Yes, I fixed it.

Comment: @smz Is there any other assumptions (for example: $K$ or $N$ large)?

Comment: No, I need this for any N or K.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
&= 1- \mathbb{P}\left(\left\vert \sum_{k=1}^{K} X_k - K\sqrt{N}\sigma\right\vert \le t\right)\\
&= 1 - \mathbb{P}\left( \underbrace{ -t + K\sqrt{N}\sigma }_{=\alpha}\le \sum_{k=1}^{K} X_k \le \underbrace{t + K\sqrt{N}\sigma}_{=\beta} \right) \\
&= 1 - \mathbb{P}\left(  \alpha - \mu \le \sum_{k=1}^{K} X_k \le \beta - \mu\right) \\
\end{align}$$
where $\left(\mu, \sigma^2  \right)$ are the mean and the variance of $\sum_{k=1}^{K} X_k $
$$\left(\mu, \sigma^2  \right) = \left(K\cdot\sqrt{2}\frac{\Gamma((N+1)/2)}{\Gamma(N/2)},K^2 \cdot  \left(N- 2\frac{\Gamma^2((N+1)/2)}{\Gamma^2(N/2)}\right) \right)$$
and then, it suffices to apply the [Selberg's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Selberg%27s_inequality) to obtain the upper bound.

Comment: Cheybev-based inequalities should be rather loose here. One expects from a Chernoff type bound to get exponentially strong bounds instead.

Comment: Theorem 3.1.1 in [High-Dimensional Probability An Introduction with Applications in Data Science](https://www.math.uci.edu/~rvershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.html#) states that $\Vert X \Vert_2 - \sqrt{N}\sigma$ has a sub-Gaussian tail. The only problem I have is to sum them up over k. Since $\Vert X \Vert_2 - \sqrt{N}\sigma$ is not centered, I don't seem to be able to utilize Hoeffding's inequality.

Comment: On my previous comment, I meant it for an $X$ that is a Gaussian random vector. The L2 norm of such random vector is equal to the $X$ in the original question.

Comment: @Mark If the question for any $N$ or $K$, then the Selberg's inequality seems still be the best answer as Chernoff type bound has only one-side bound (indeed, the problem is to find the bounds for some kinds of expression $\mathbb{P}(X \ge a) + \mathbb{P}(X \le b)$. We can have bounds for $\mathbb{P}(X \ge a)$ thanks to Chernoff bound, but what's about $\mathbb{P}(X \le -a)$)?